# Move to variables with same name

Tags: cobol

My Cobol structure:

```
01. MyData.
    02. Corp-Entity
        03. Corp-Branch1.
            04. Address.
                05. AddressLine1 PIC X(20).
                05. AddressLine2 PIC X(20).
                05. PostalCode   PIC 9(05).
    02. PIC-Entity.
        03. Address.
            04. AddressLine1 PIC X(20).
            04. AddressLine2 PIC X(20).
            04. PostalCode   PIC 9(05).
```

I have the data to move in `Address of Corp-Entity` and another data to move in `Address of PIC-Entity`

But when I try to move the value

```
move valueAddressLine1 to AddressLine1 
                       of Address
                       of PIC-Entity
```

Error Message:

> "AddressLine1 of Address of PIC-Entity" was not a uniquely defined name.
> The definition to be used could not be determined from the context.  The reference to the name was discarded.

How to move `'valueAddressLine1'` to `AddressLine1 of Address of PIC-Entity`?

Comment: Drop the periods after the level numbers to create valid COBOL.

Comment: Which COBOL compiler and version are you using?

Comment: The document you link states that RCCOBXML is case sensitive, so you should use lowercase variable names for your structures.

Could you please explain exacly how it isn't working (compilation error, runtime error, correct execution yielding bad values...) ?

Comment: @DavidLarochette : Just update the more detail of the question

Comment: Depending on your compiler ADDRESS may be a reserved word.  Try changing it to something else like Address-x.

Comment: @JimCastro it just sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it to:

```
move valueAddressLine1 to AddressLine1 
                   in Address
                   in PIC-Entity
                   in MyData
```

most likely you have PIC-Entity that has same structure somewhere else outside MyData definition.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, Its works.
But its not worked on my (Q2). Any advice?

Comment: @ErgaKandly fix the record definition (and possibly accept the answer). Note: you don't have to "full qualify", it should be enough to have `to AddressLine1 in PIC-Entity`.

Comment: @ErgaKandly, i believe that if you want to access some of the definitions, they must be uniqly defined in your data structure.
you can also try to check QUALIFY(EXTEND) compile option, to access non-unique definitions, however it might be more complicated.
you can read more about it here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSUFAU_1.0.0/com.ibm.ent.cbl.zos.doc/PGandLR/ui/up3090.html

Comment: @SimonSobisch The structure must like that. because i have to generate it to be XML File using XML Generate function. The problem is I can't move a value to 05.AddressLine1 because the structure same with 06. AddressLine1

Comment: @VadimKo The structure must like that. because i have to generate it to be XML File using XML Generate function. The problem is I can't move a value to 05.AddressLine1 because the structure same with 06.AddressLine1

Comment: @ErgaKandly That's a completely different question that is only indirectly related to this one... as this is a Q+A side: please accept the answer and create a new question "how to adjust the generated name with XML GENERATE" (and get an answer from someone linking the IBM documentation that specifies how to adjust a name)

Comment: @SimonSobisch Ahh ok i'll create new question. Thank you Simon